# TypeError: pos is undefined error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting TypeError: pos is undefined on below code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var s = $("#col-scroll");
    var pos = s.position();                   
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (windowpos+60 >= pos.top) {
            s.addClass("col-fixed");
        } else {
            s.removeClass("col-fixed");
        }
    });
});
```

Code used to work fine. Dont know why it is giving an error. Can someone tell me what is the issue here? Really appropriated your help.

Comment: `.position()` returning `undefined` may mean that `s` is empty / `$("#col-scroll")` didn't match an existing element. ([Is there an “exists” function for jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31044/is-there-an-exists-function-for-jquery))

Comment: It is telling you that `pos` in undefined, so are you sure you are addressing this correctly? `position()` get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent. So if this can not be found you `var  s`  is undefined.

Comment: @Franco thank you, your correct. My div was deleted. Please add as a answer so i can accept it. Thanks again

Comment: @Jordyn answer is added. Good luck and happy coding. :)

Comment: @Franco thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is telling you that pos in undefined, so are you sure you are addressing this correctly? position() get the current coordinates of the first element in the set of matched elements, relative to the offset parent. So if this can not be found you var s is undefined.